# How to create an array with the same key?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, key

both from the array:

```
$g = array("Drama", "Crime");
```

do:

```
$genre = array("genre" => "Drama", "genre" => "Crime");
```

We need to do a query to the database mongoDB, essentially with this condition:

```
genre = 'Drama' OR genre = 'Crime'
```

Here's why I tried:

```
find(array("genre" => "Drama", "genre" => "Crime"))
```

Due to the fact that the keys are the same, it is impossible to create such an array. How can I perform the desired query?

**UPD**
The right solution:

```
$g = array("Drama", "Crime");
find(array("genre" => array('$in' => $g)))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe we could make better suggestions if we understood the context of what you're doing.

Comment: You cannot have 2 of the same keys in an array.  How would it know which you want?  If you did that, the 2nd element would overwrite the 1st. Why do you need the elements to have keys?  What's wrong with `$g`?

Comment: @Rocket, We need to do a query to the database mongoDB.

Comment: Are you trying to query where `movieGenre` is either `Drama` OR `Crime`? I've not used MongoDB, but according to [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/OR+operations+in+query+expressions), it might be something like this: `array("genre" => array('$in' => array("Drama", "Crime")))`. Just a guess. _(Note: you must use single quotes around `$in` because it's a string, not a variable.)_

Comment: @Wiseguy, thank you very much for your time, sorry that does not carefully considered the documentation.

Comment: @Wiseguy You should have submitted that as an answer so that Art Pip could have accepted it, but /clap for not answering without knowing for sure about it!

Comment: @Adanion Didn't know at the time if it was correct. Oh well; it has since been submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about MongoDB (I had to Google this: [Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/OR+operations+in+query+expressions)), but there is an `$in` operator.  You want `genere IN ("Drama", "Crime")`

I think this is how you do it in PHP/MongoDB

```
find(array("genre" => array('$in' => array("Drama", "Crime"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array inside of an array:

```
$genre = array(
    "genre" => array(
        "Drama",
        "Crime"
    )
);
```

Comment: I need to create a query in mongoDB. This option does not work!

Comment: @ArtPip: Nice of you to say! My **Crystal Ball** is out of order today, sorry for not knowing that myself!

Comment: I'm sorry, that did not specify it once.